# SlidesJS - TypeError: $(...).slidesjs is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror, slidesjs

I'm trying to implement the SlidesJS plugin on my site, but when the page loads i get the following error:

```
TypeError: $(...).slidesjs is not a function
```

My html is:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="slides">
                <img src="<?= img('slides/example-slide-1.jpg') ?>" alt="photo 1">
                <img src="<?= img('slides/example-slide-2.jpg') ?>" alt="photo 2">
                <img src="<?= img('slides/example-slide-3.jpg') ?>" alt="photo 3">
                <img src="<?= img('slides/example-slide-4.jpg') ?>" alt="photo 4">
                <a href="#" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-left icon-large"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-right icon-large"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css file contains:

```
.slider #slides {
    display: none;
}
```

And my js file contains:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    ...

    $("#slides").slidesjs({
            width: 1000,
            height: 290
        });
    }
```

I've included both jQuery and the plugin's specific script, but I still get this error.
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by moving the file inclusion to the page footer.

Comment: Your solution works. Don't know who down-voted your answer...I have up-voted your answer. :)

Comment: @UjwalaKhaire Thanks! Please mark my answer as the correct one as well, so other people easily can see it's the right one.