# SlidesJS TypeError unidentified is not an function in Safari on Mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, safari, slidesjs

I have the same problem as described here and my code is pretty much similar:

[SlidesJS - TypeError: $(...).slidesjs is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531590/slidesjs-typeerror-slidesjs-is-not-a-function/18046620#18046620)

So when I try to load the page in Safari the pictures don't load and I get the error "TypeError 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#slides').slidesjs')". I did the thing with moving the script declaration from the head to the body and it worked for Safari on Windows but it didn't work for Safari on Mac(for some reason). Works perfectly on every other browser. So now I'm not really sure what else I could do to fix this. Any Ideas?

Just to be thorough I'll post my code.

My HTML:

```
<head>              
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="Script/slides.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Script/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <section class="container">            
        <div id="slides">
            <img src="Images/background/01ok.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img src="Images/background/02ok_A.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img src="Images/background/03ok.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

My script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slides').slidesjs({ 
        height: 400,
        navigation: false,
        pagination: false,
        effect: {
            fade: {
                speed: 1200
            }
        },
        play: {
            active: false,
            auto: true,
            interval: 5000,
            pauseOnHover: false,
            effect: "fade"
       }
    });
});
```

My CSS:

```
.container {    
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}

#slides {
    display: none;
}

#slides img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: The thing is it seems to work perfectly for me.. I see that there is definitely some issue with the path of the scripts or the way they are included.

Comment: Can you please verify the paths to your pictures (case-sensitive) may be..

Comment: Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wLyqt56k/

Comment: So I've changed everything to be lowercase(folders and files). And it didn't help. I've seen that you included the scripts beneath the images so just to be sure I did that as well but with no luck.